# Getting php output from url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im trying to get a number that im writing out in a .php file and into a .js file.

I have a javascript function that inputs data to mySQL on each click and now I need to get this data out again to display on the page.

Trying to do a simple hour to make HTML5 app, but hour is almost up and im lost.

So my php file looks like this:

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';

$tCount = mysql_query ("SELECT SUM(clicks) FROM clicks");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tCount)){ 

    $totalCounts = $row['SUM(clicks)'];   
}

?>

    <span id="foo"><? echo $totalCounts; ?></span>
```

And as you can see I just get every row from the table and SUM it out. 
Now I need to display this on the screen but on each click that happends from me or a another user, the totalCounts will update itself.

And I can not just echo this out in the index file, this must be external so need need to know if I can parseINT this out from **url** or other way.

Thank you in advance

Comment: where is your js & full html?

Comment: You should post all your code (JS and PHP)

Comment: No, **for the love of God** PLEASE DON'T POST "*your js & full html*" or "*all your code*".  Try to demonstrate your problem using a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) instead: usually by reducing your code to the minimum that is necessary.

Comment: The only js I have now is input to mySQL and that works fine, so no need to post that. Im looking for a small help on how to archive this: Output total clicks from every user combine on every click. And the above code is my full php code to get all clicks from every user and add them together, now I need to output this with js. And can't do it with var code = "<?php echo $totalCounts; ">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not clear, though...

php

```
echo json_encode(array('totalCounts' => $totalCounts));
```

js using jquery

```
function set(){
      $.ajax({
                url: "tophp",
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    var j = JSON.parse(data);
                    $("foo").text(j.totalCounts);
                }
         });
}
```

need to call above ajax function from using timer.
`setInterval(set,1000)`;
cant change rendered html page from server like observer design pattern.

Comment: Thanks, this is what im looking for! Great job

Answer (score 0):

```
$tCount = mysql_query ("SELECT SUM(clicks) as total FROM clicks");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tCount)){ 

$totalCounts = $row['total']; }
```

try this instead

Comment: Thanks but my php code works as it is, but its better with what you wrote :)